# JPA OneToOne Mapping doesn't update child but instead inserts a new one

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**RuleEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rules")
public class RuleEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer RuleId;
    
    @Column(name = "rule_expression")
    private String RuleExpression;
    
    @Column(name = "rule_frequncy")
    private Integer RuleFrequency;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="alert_id")
    private AlertEntity alertEntity;
}
```

**AlertEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alerts")
public class AlertEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "alert_id")
    private Integer alertId;

    @Column(name = "action")
    private String alertAction;
}
```

**RuleRepository**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleEntity, Integer>{}
```

**Code**

```
RuleEntity ruleEntity= new RuleEntity();
AlertEntity alertEntity = new AlertEntity();
alertEntity.setAlertAction(data.getAlertAction());
ruleEntity.setAlertEntity(alertEntity);
if(newRule) ruleEntity.setRuleId(data.getRuleId());
ruleEntity.setRuleExpression(data.getRuleExpression());
ruleEntity.setRuleFrequency(data.getRuleFrequency());
ruleRepository.save(ruleEntity);
```

When I use `ruleRepository.save(ruleEntity)` and don't provide `ruleEntity.RuleId` a new rule and alert are inserted and alert primary key is provided in **alert_id** column of the **rules** table.

If I provide `ruleEntity.RuleId` and save `ruleEntity` then data associated with RuleId gets updated but new row gets inserted in **alerts** table.

What I want is to update existing alert by using id from **rules** table. How to achieve this?

Comment: How to you populate `alertEntity` during the "update" use-case? To not create a new `AlertEntity` you have to provide the `RuleEntity` with a managed `AlertEntity` of course.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, Can you give example

Comment: You haven't included the code where you call `RuleRepository`

Comment: @Smutje I have added the code for the same in Question

Comment: What is `data`? Also, if you just create a new `MonitorAlertEntity` and set it on the `ruleEntity` instead of using an existing one (from the database) it shouldn't be surprising that Hibernate creates a new row for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this logic:

```
if(newRule) ruleEntity.setRuleId(data.getRuleId());
```

you should try to fetch the possibly existing rule, something like:

```
RuleEntity ruleEntity;
if(newRule) {
    ruleEntity = new RuleEntity();
} else {
    ruleEntity = ruleRepository.findById(data.getRuleId())
}
```

Now depending on if `ruleEntity` has `alertEntity` already you just `getAlertEntity()` and update it before saving. If not you just create a new one and then `setAlertEntity(aNewAlertEntity)` with values from `data` before saving.

Note that this is simplified example and you need to take care of possible `Optional` chacks and so on but the basic idea should be clear.